# ORB's detectAndCompute returns None for a slightly different image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I have some kind of alignment task to do. In the process, I need to extract descriptors and keypoints.
I'm using the following simple code for 2 images that are almost identical, with the same shape:

```
orb = cv2.ORB_create(maxFeatures)
(kpsA, descsA) = orb.detectAndCompute(image, None)
(kpsB, descsB) = orb.detectAndCompute(template, None)
```

[image: ORB fails with the image on the left, but fine with the right one]

ORB fails with the image on the left, but fine with the right one.

The returned `(kpsA, descsA)` are fine, but `len(kpsB)==0` and `descsB==None` and I can't find the reason for that.

Comment: You do not have good features to match. No corners and you have horizontal symmetry so many parts of one image match many parts of the other. So all of them have poor scores and are likely thrown out. You might be better just averaging the image to one column and matching simply on the spacing between the white lines. So a 1D problem rather than 2D

Comment: @fmw42 I haven't got to the matching part. My question is how come one of this images is good enough for extracting the descriptors and the other isn't.

Comment: How do you know that? If you swap the two images, do you have the same issue. I do not see how either is any good at getting good features to match.

Comment: @fmw42 There's nothing to do with swapping them - tried and got the same thing. Also same when detecting just one image.

Comment: I think you should just deal with this as a 1D registration as I mentioned above. I do not know what to tell you about your 2D issue with ORB.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a year since you asked the question but I want to suggest you try this. A plausible reason you see `None` for some images is because the default value of the threshold in the function is too high. So just play with the `fastThreshold` and `edgeThreshold` params and see if it works for you.

A good sanity check will be to set

```
orb = cv2.ORB_create(fastThreshold=0, edgeThreshold=0)
```

and see what's happen.

Next, you can chose whether to ignore these images or to try a smaller threshold.

The full explanation of the function params is here in the [opencv doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.4/db/d95/classcv_1_1ORB.html).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, ORB fails to detect any features on the left image and probably only finds few features on the right image.

Instead consider doing image alignment/ image registration using a method that is not feature based. Have a look at dense optical flow algorithms such as [cv::optflow::DenseRLOFOpticalFlow](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/df/d59/classcv_1_1optflow_1_1DenseRLOFOpticalFlow.html).

With that being said, your task looks challenging. Even humans will have difficulties solving it well. Good luck.